# Dojo dgrid: no highlight on selection in invisible part of the grid

Tags: dojo, selection, dgrid

I have a problem with a selection in OnDemandGrid( dojo 1.12.1) and I need some help.
A part of my grid is hidden on creation and this makes the selection 'single' works  weird, the selection is active only on visible part of the content. While I scroll I have no more the highlight on my row [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GSEj.png). 
However if I apply a sort on a column, the content is refreshed and the whole row becomes selectable.

The example on this page works for EnhancedGrid in selectionMode: 'single' without bugs on a hidden part of a content after loading. 
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Selector.html, any ideas how to acheve it?

What could I do while creating OnDemandGrid to resolve the problem? I've tried to put a css parameter box-sizing: border-box, but it didn't help me.

There are some simular issues for enchancedgrid, but the solition isn't good for me, maybe it's because I'm using the OnDemandGrid (
dojo EnchancedGrid items do not select programmatically in invisible part of the view)

```
require([
     ...
    'dojo/store/Memory',
    'dgrid/OnDemandGrid',
    'dgrid/Selection',
    'dgrid/extensions/ColumnResizer',
    'dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry'

], function (Memory, OnDemandGrid, Selection, ColumnResizer, DijitRegistry ) {
     var columNs = {First_Name: {label: 'First Name'},
                    Last_Name: {label: 'Last Name'},
                    hello: {label: 'hello'},
                    age: {label: 'age'},
                    size: {label: 'size'},
                    name: {label: 'name'},
                    code: {label: 'code'},
                    id: {label: 'id'},
                    mdp: {label: 'mdp'},
                    username: {label: 'username'},
                    grid: {label: 'grid'}
                    };

   var store = new Memory({ data: createData() });  

   var CustomGrid = declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection, ColumnResizer, DijitRegistry]);

   var grid = new CustomGrid({
                        selectionMode: 'single',
                        cellNavigation: false, 
                        store: store, 
                        columns: columNs
                    }, 'grid');          
   grid.startup();



   function createData() {
        var data = [];
        var column;
        var i;
        var item;

        for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            item = {};
            for (column in { First_Name: 1, Last_Name: 1, hello: 1, age: 1, size: 1, name: 1, code: 1, id: 1, mdp: 1, username: 1, grid: 1 }) {
                item.id = i;
                item[column] = column + '_' + (i + 1);
            }
            data.push(item);
        }

        return data;
    }
});

//css
.dgrid {
    height: 25em !important;
    width: 100%;
}
.dgrid .dgrid-scroller {
    margin-top: 24px !important; 
}
.dgrid-cell { 
    width: 70px !important;
}
.dgrid-column-set-scroller {
display: inline-block;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

}

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your problem. See on the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qr857ypa/5/).

One difference in that I replaced dojo/store/Memory, which was giving me an error (if you don't get this error maybe you are using a dgrid version older that 0.4 ?), with dstore/Memory.

Then the fiddle is using dojo 1.12.2 (should make no difference with 1.12.1), and dgrid / dstore 1.1.0 (that could explain the difference if you are using a significantly older version). It also uses dijit's claro.css & dgrid's dgrid.css. See below (extracted from the jsfiddle) the part of your source code that I modified:

```
require({
    packages: [
        {
            name: 'dgrid',
            location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0'
        },
        {
            name: 'dstore',
            location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dstore/v1.1.0'
        }
    ]
},[
            "dojo/_base/declare",
            'dstore/Memory',
            'dgrid/OnDemandGrid',
            'dgrid/Selection',
            'dgrid/extensions/ColumnResizer',
            'dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry'

], function (declare, Memory, OnDemandGrid, Selection, ColumnResizer, DijitRegistry ) {
```